# github new branch creation and pull request - using REST API

Tags: rest, github, github-api

I need to create a branch and then do a pull request using REST API. First i tired to create a new branch with the following curl command.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# curl -d '{ "ref": "refs/heads/new_branch", "sha": "aa218f56b14c9653891f9e74264a383fa43fefbd" }' -u user-name -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/user-name/myrepo/git/refs
Enter host password for user 'user-name':
{
  "message": "Object does not exist",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#create-a-reference"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following [link](https://gist.github.com/potherca/3964930) to review the commands for creating a new branch (AKA: refs) and this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#user-agent-required) to review how to validate the credentials, I could create a new empty branch. If you use the command without the validation, you will get a confusing answer

> "message": "Not Found"

I followed this step to create a new branch named:

1. Get the SHA using this command -> GET [https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repository}/git/refs/heads](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepository%7D/git/refs/heads) and copy one SHA (In my case, all are the same)
2. Create a token using this [link](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and copy it. This token will be used in the parameter to create the branch.
3. Create the new branch using this command -> POST [https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repository}/git/refs](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepository%7D/git/refs), setting a basic authorization {username}:{token} in the header and in the body the follow content:

   {
   "ref": "refs/heads/{BranchName}",
   "sha": "{SHA copied in the step 1}"
   }
4. Finally, you will obtain the information of the new branch

Answer (score 0):

a good alternative is to use hub instead. https://github.com/github/hub
For example:

- if you haven't cloned the repo yet:

  > hub checkout [PULLREQ-URL]
- if you have a repo cloned already, and just want a new branch

  > hub checkout [BRANCH]

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative (since February 2020) is to use the [new GitHub cli](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-02-12-github-cli-is-now-in-beta/), which replaces/offers an alternative to [`github/hub`](https://github.com/github/hub).

See "[GitHub CLI is now in beta](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-02-12-github-cli-is-now-in-beta/) " and "[Supercharge your command line experience](https://github.blog/2020-02-12-supercharge-your-command-line-experience-github-cli-is-now-in-beta/)":

It is [**cli.github.com**](https://cli.github.com/).

If will create a fork for you:

Create a pull request

> Create a branch, make several commits to fix the bug described in the issue, and use `gh` to create a pull request to share your contribution.

[image: cli create pr -- https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/10404068/74261506-35df4080-4cb0-11ea-9285-c41583009e6c.png?ssl=1]

> By using GitHub CLI to create pull requests, it also automatically creates a fork when you don’t already have one, and it pushes your branch and creates your pull request to get your change merged.